# GIT thinks db has been updated after tests

Tags: git, h2

I have an eclipse jpa project with some tests that use a dummy h2 database to verify the correct loading of data.  No new data is presisted to the dummy db

Every time I run the tests the db is considered modified by GIT.  How can I avoid the unnecessary checking in of new versions of the database; it's my understanding that a binary file will just get completely replaced, unnecessarily inflating my repo.

Comment: Don't know h2, but probably it change the database content for example by creating temporary tables or something like that (cache, ...). Why you don't just reset the database file to the state of the repository (pre-test)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on the db file after you checkout your working copy / branch. You can also try using `git update-index --skip-worktree`

Comment: Is there a permanent way to assume unchanged?  Seems extreme to have to exec a git command in the tear-down of the test.

Comment: @Pengin - no you don't have to do that in the "teardown" - Do it once on your working copy. It doesn't get changed, but you for a more "permanent" one try `git update-index --skip-worktree`

Answer (score 1):

Make the database [read only](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#read_only)

Answer (score 1):

H2 data files are rebuilt if they don't exist, right?  If so, or you don't care, add the name of the data files to your [.gitignore](http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html) file.